# Tarot card game strategies

Tags: tarot

I love this game and play quite regularly. Yet I don't seem to be able to advance my strategy level. Does anyone know of any decent resources that could help me here? I can handle it written in French.

Comment: Would you be more specific about the game you are talking about?

Comment: The game: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_tarot. My question... well I know the rules but I'd really like to read a guide that's more strategy based (advice on internet sites, books, etc). But it seems this kind of question is too "broad".